# Getting "setter" type of Record

Tags: haskell

If I have a record like this:

```
data PersonR = PersonR { firstName :: String
                       , lastName :: String
                       } deriving Show
```

And wanting to check `firstName`'s type:

```
firstName :: PersonR -> String
```

But this would be a typical getter in OOP. Since in Haskell variables are immutable, how can I see the setter with the `:t` command? I am assuming it would be:

```
:: PersonR -> String -> PersonR
```

But how can I get this?

Comment: Are you trying to make a setter for `PersonR`?

Comment: @randomusername no, I just want to confirm my reasoning.

Comment: Yes, this is generally the type signature for a purely functional setter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haskell doesn't define a setter function for you. The best approximation is a special syntax which allows you to conveniently create a new record from an old one while altering certain fields.

Example:

```
john = PersonR "John" "Doe"  -- same as PersonR { firstName = "John", lastName = "Doe" }

jane = john { firstName = "Jane" }
```

The value `jane` is now equal to `Person "Jane" "Doe"`.

Using this syntax you can create your own setter function:

```
setLastName :: PersonR -> String -> PersonR
setLastName person surname = person { lastName = surName }
```

but you might find it just as convenient to use the special syntax itself.